# new build ios app version not appear in app store connect build list?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I submit new version in app store connect,
they reject the version ,I upload new version from Xcode and it is successfully  uploaded. but when i go to the rejected version in app store connect and want to add the new build , it is not appear , only the rejected build appear,

any one knows why??

i try upload new version many times , so now there are many uploaded versions , which not appear in app store connect!

Comment: Try removing rejected build first, once removed you will have option to upload a new build

Comment: thank you, i do that but still , the rejected version appear only

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, there are contributors here who will enjoy helping you find an answer. To help them solve your issue have a read of these useful guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem
run this in terminal:

> flutter build ios --release

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a build, it starts *Processing*. Once it is done, it will appear in that **Builds** section and you can select it for the version you want to submit. You can see all builds in **Activity** section in App Store Connect.

Comment: thats the problem , build not appear there, before they were appear but after they reject this version , no builds appear only the rejected one appear in build list.